# Getting Parent Objects with Functions in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I am trying to learn alloy but i am having a hard time finding proper learning material.
So i am trying some models by myself and see if they works.

I wanted to find and return the clinics containing the given doctor with the function but it is not working. How can i do this without changing the Clinic and Doctor?

```
abstract sig Clinic {
    doctors : set Doctor
}
abstract sig Doctor {}

fun getClinicsOfDoctor [ d : Doctor ] : set Clinic {
    all c : Clinic | d in c.doctors
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What material have you looked at? Try the [Alloy book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262017156). Also see tutorials and papers on the Alloy [website](http://alloy.mit.edu).

What's wrong with your model is that the body of your function is a formula. It should instead be an expression. Any of the following will work

```
doctors.d
d.~doctors
{c: Clinic | d in c.doctors}
```